# Cannot find the Umbraco route in the route values

Tags: asp.net, razor, umbraco

I've been spending my time building a site with Umbraco and I'm almost done except I can't get the HttpPost for my Contact View to work. As I get the following error:
[image]

I've tried quite a few things I found around here and on Umbraco Forums but nothing has been useful so far, at first I thought it was the validation itself so I changed that and even changed the AJAX action but nothing worked, after debugging I found this error but I have no idea how to approach a solution.

This is the entire controller code:

```
  public class ContactSurfaceController : SurfaceController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return PartialView("ContactView", new ContactViewModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [NotChildAction]
        public ActionResult Submit(ContactViewModel form)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Json(new { Success = false });
            }

            SectionContact currSection = (SectionContact)Umbraco.TypedContent(form.CurrentSectionId);

            string mailTo = currSection.AdministratorsEmail;
            string mailFrom = currSection.NotificationMailFrom;
            string mailFromAlias = currSection.NotificationMailSenderAlias;
            string message = string.Concat(currSection.NotificationEmailBody, "<br/><br/>", umbraco.library.StripHtml(form.Message));

            //Use predefined subject. If predefined subject is not defined, use current subject from form (if any)
            string subject = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currSection.NotificationEmailSubject)) ? form.Subject : currSection.NotificationEmailSubject;

            //If all else fails, use standard subject from dictionary.
            subject = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(subject)) ? Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("ContactForm.Subject") : subject;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(form.Name))
            {
                sb.Append("Name:");
                sb.Append("<br/>");
                sb.Append(form.Name);
                sb.Append("<br/><br/>");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(form.Subject))
            {
                sb.Append("Subject:");
                sb.Append("<br/>");
                sb.Append(form.Subject);
                sb.Append("<br/><br/>");
            }

            sb.Append("Email: ");
            sb.Append("<br/>");
            sb.Append(form.Email);
            sb.Append("<br/><br/>");

            sb.Append("Message: ");
            sb.Append("<br/>");
            sb.Append(umbraco.library.ReplaceLineBreaks(message));
            sb.Append("<br/><br/>");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currSection.Dropdown1Values))
            {
                sb.Append(currSection.Dropdown1Values.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\n\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]);
                sb.Append("<br/>");
                sb.Append(form.DropDown1);
                sb.Append("<br/><br/>");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currSection.Dropdown2Values))
            {
                sb.Append(currSection.Dropdown2Values.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\n\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]);
                sb.Append("<br/>");
                sb.Append(form.DropDown2);
                sb.Append("<br/><br/>");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Utils.SendEmail(mailFrom, mailFromAlias, mailTo, subject, sb.ToString());
            }

            return Json(new { Success = true });
        }


    }
```

Here is the partial view:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<SectionContact>

@using DotSee.Models;
@using DotSee.UmbracoExtensions;

@{

    SectionContact currSection = Model;
    int currSectionId = currSection.Id;

    string[] dropDown1Data = currSection.Dropdown1Values.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\n\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string[] dropDown2Data = currSection.Dropdown2Values.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\n\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

}

<section id="contactForm_@currSectionId" class="@currSection.GetSectionEffectCssClass() ptb-60 ptb-sm-60">
    <div class="container">

        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currSection.IntroText) || !currSection.HideTitle)
        {

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">

                    @if (!currSection.HideTitle)
                    {
                        <h3>@currSection.Name</h3>
                    }

                    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currSection.IntroText))
                    {
                        <p class="lead">@currSection.IntroText</p>
                    }

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer-15"></div>
        }

        @Html.Partial("ContactView", new ContactViewModel()
                   , new ViewDataDictionary
                   {
                         { "currSectionId", currSection.Id }
                       , { "hideSubject", currSection.HideSubject }
                       , { "hideName", currSection.HideName }
                       , { "dropDown1Data", dropDown1Data }
                       , { "dropDown2Data", dropDown2Data }
                   })
        </div>
</section>
```

And finally this is the view contact view:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<ContactViewModel>
@using DotSee.UmbracoExtensions
@using DotSee.Models
@using DotSee.Controllers
@using Umbraco.Web
@using ClientDependency.Core.Mvc;

@{
    Html.RequiresJs("/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js",9999);
    Html.RequiresJs("/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js", 9999);
    Html.RequiresJs("/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js", 9999);

    int currSectionId = Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["currSectionId"]);
    bool hideSubject = (bool)ViewData["hideSubject"];
    bool hideName = (bool)ViewData["hideName"];
    string[] dropDown1Data = (ViewData["dropDown1Data"] as string[]);
    string[] dropDown2Data = (ViewData["dropDown2Data"] as string[]);
}


        <div class="row">
            <div id="contactFormMessages" class="ptb-0 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">

                <h6 id="contactSuccess" class="successContent">
                    <i class="fa fa-check left" style="color: #5cb45d;"></i>@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("ContactForm.Success")
                </h6>

                <h6 class="errorContent">
                    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle left" style="color: #e1534f;"></i>@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("ContactForm.Failure")
                </h6>

               </div>

            <div id="contactFormHolder" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Submit", "ContactSurface", new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    OnFailure = "ShowContactError",
                    OnSuccess = "ShowContactSuccess",
                }))
                {

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CurrentSectionId, new { Value = Convert.ToInt32(currSectionId) })
                    if (!hideName)
                    {
                        <div class="form-field-wrapper">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @Placeholder = "Name", @class = "input-sm form-full" })
                        </div>
                    }
                    <div class="form-field-wrapper">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @Placeholder = "Email", @class = "input-sm form-full" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("ContactForm.Email.Invalid"))
                    </div>
                    if (!hideSubject)
                    {
                        <div class="form-field-wrapper">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Subject, new { @Placeholder = "Subject", @class = "input-sm form-full" })
                        </div>
                    }
                    <div class="form-field-wrapper">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @Placeholder = "Content", @class = "form-full", @rows = 7 })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message, Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("ContactForm.Message.Required"))
                    </div>
                    if (dropDown1Data != null && dropDown1Data.Length > 1)
                    {
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DropDown1, dropDown1Data.Select(f => new SelectListItem { Value = f, Text = f }).Skip(1), dropDown1Data[0], new { @class = "form-full" })
                    }
                    if (dropDown2Data != null && dropDown2Data.Length > 1)
                    {
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DropDown2, dropDown2Data.Select(f => new SelectListItem { Value = f, Text = f }).Skip(1), dropDown2Data[0], new { @class = "form-full" })
                    }
                    <button class="btn btn-md btn-black form-full" type="submit" id="form-submit" name="submit">@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("ContactForm.Submit")</button>
                }
            </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowContactError() {
         $(".errorContent").show();
            $("#contactFormHolder").hide();
    }

    function ShowContactSuccess(arg) {
        if (arg.Success === true) {
            $("#contactSuccess").show();
            $("#contactFormHolder").hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $(".successContent").show();
            $("#contactFormHolder").hide();

        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Ajax.BeginForm in Umbraco. You have to create your own Ajax form handler and route it to ~/Umbraco/Api/Contact/Submit

For this to work, your controller has to inherit from UmbracoApiController and not SurfaceController.

If you want to use MVC instead of WebAPI you should use the Html.BeginUmbracoForm helper. In this case your controller should be a SurfaceController.

[Umbraco WebApi](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/)